# str_replace for dynamic form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, dynamic

I working with  this dynamic form

```
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Input Data</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function tambahHobi() {
            var idf = document.getElementById("idf").value;
            var stre;
            stre="<p id='srow" + idf + "'><input type='text' size='40' name='rincian_hobi[]' placeholder='Masukkan Hobi' /> <a href='#' style=\"color:#3399FD;\" onclick='hapusElemen(\"#srow" + idf + "\"); return false;'>Hapus</a></p>";
            $("#divHobi").append(stre); 
            idf = (idf-1) + 2;
            document.getElementById("idf").value = idf;
        }
    function hapusElemen(idf) {
            $(idf).remove();
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h2>Input Data</h2>
<form method="post" action="doc.php">
    <input id="idf" value="1" type="hidden" />
    <p>  Nomor Kotak : <input name="nama" type="text" id="nama" size="40"> </p>
    <p> Kode :<select name="kode">
    <option></option>
    <option value="BMN">BMN</option>
    <option value="KP">KP</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="KU">KU</option>
    <p>  No : <input name="nokode" type="text" id="nama" size="40"> </p>
    <p>  TAHUN : <input name="tahun" type="text" id="nama" size="40"> </p>

    <button type="button"  onclick="tambahHobi(); return false;">Tambah Rincian</button>
    <div id="divHobi"></div>
    <button type="submit">Simpan</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont using database, so i just generate the form in to ms.Word document
 
and this is the doc.php

```
<?php

$nama=$_POST['nama'];
        $kode=$_POST['kode'];
        $nokode=$_POST['nokode'];
        $tahun=$_POST['tahun'];
       if(isset($_POST["rincian_hobi"]))
                    {
                        $hoby=$_POST["rincian_hobi"];
                        reset($hoby);
                        while (list($key, $value) = each($hoby)) 
                            {
                                $rincian_hoby   =$_POST["rincian_hobi"][$key];
                            }
                    }

    $document = file_get_contents("doc.rtf");

$document = str_replace("%%NAMA%%", $nama, $document);
$document = str_replace("%%KODE%%", $kode, $document);
$document = str_replace("%%NOKODE%%", $nokode, $document);
$document = str_replace("%%TAHUN%%", $tahun, $document);
$document = str_replace("%%HOBI%%",  $rincian_hoby, $document);


header("Content-type: application/msword");
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=doc.rtf");
header("Content-length: " . strlen($document));
echo $document;

?>
```

but the **str_replace on %%HOBI%%**, didn't work well
it's just replace the last input from the form, not all 
can somebody please tell me what's wrong
 thx

Comment: You don't show what is in your doc.rtf which could perhaps clarify the situation.

Comment: the rtf file is just simple like : 
` %%NAMA%%
%%KODE%%
%%NOKODE%%
%%TAHUN%%
%%HOBI%%
`
 and if i input into the the dynamic form, the str_replace %%HOBI%% just preview the last record, not all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the mistake...

```
       if(isset($_POST["rincian_hobi"]))
                {
                    $hoby=$_POST["rincian_hobi"];
                    reset($hoby);
                    while (list($key, $value) = each($hoby)) 
                        {
                            $rincian_hoby   =$_POST["rincian_hobi"][$key];
                        }
                }
```

In the above code, you are $rincian_hoby   =$_POST["rincian_hobi"][$key]; which is wrong.  It should be,

```
           if(isset($_POST["rincian_hobi"]))
                {
                    $hoby=$_POST["rincian_hobi"];
                    reset($hoby);
                    while (list($key, $value) = each($hoby)) 
                        {
                            $rincian_hoby .= $_POST["rincian_hobi"][$key] . ",";
                        }
                    $rincian_hoby = substr($rincian_hoby,0,-1);
                }
```

Comment: can u please help once again, how to put the result of $rincian_hoby vertically
thx a lot

Comment: Instead of , use <br/> tag like this - $rincian_hoby .= $_POST["rincian_hobi"][$key] . "<br/>"; and then $rincian_hoby = substr($rincian_hoby,0,-5);

Comment: thx before for ur answer, but  that's not working, 
-PS: the output is a document with ekstension .rtf -